# How do I know if a graphics card is sufficient for a given external monitor? (Time-sensitive)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

[This is time-sensitive because the deal I want to get closes soon. Any helpful ideas re: the below would be greatly appreciated]

I have mid-2012 MBP 13in and I run it at home connected to an Acer 24 inch monitor which has been great for the past couple years.

Basically, I have an opportunity to get a highly discounted HP Pavilion **32inch QHD Wide-Viewing Angle Display Monitor**. Has DisplayPort and 2 HDMI connects, and a 2560x1440 resolution.

I read some Amazon reviews and many of them mentioned making sure that your video card can support the resolution the monitor requires. **My video card is the Intel HD Graphics 4000** that came with the computer.

**Will I run into problems with this potential purchase and, if so, what sort of problem(s) and how much would they perhaps cost me to remedy?** Thanks!

Comment: This is the aforementioned 32inch monitor: https://www.amazon.com/HP-Pavilion-32-inch-Wide-Viewing-Display/dp/B01FGCJBGK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html), the mid-2012 MacBook Pro can *support an external monitor* with a resolution of 2560x1600.

This means that your Intel HD Graphics 4000 chip is capable of supporting your monitor.  However, you should be aware that the [HD 4000 uses shared memory](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000-Benchmarked.73567.0.html) (meaning it takes up to 1.5GB of RAM from the system).

Personally, I would upgrade your memory to the maximum amount and again, according to EveryMac.com, you can upgrade it to [16GB of PC3-12800 SO-DIMM Memory](http://radnex.us/Crucial-PC-3-12800-SODIMM).  This will ensure that your integrated graphics chip and the system has enough memory to deliver the best graphics performance it possibly can.

Also, regarding the monitor connection, I would avoid converting DisplayPort to HDMI and just stick with DisplayPort (go mDP to DP).

Comment: Hey, great information, thank you! I have 16GB RAM already, so I've got that step taken care of. Very much appreciate the extra tip re: the DisplayPort and HDMI connection.